# QuaggaJS with Angular 2 problems

Tags: angular, quaggajs

I'm trying to use QuaggaJS with Angular 2. I have the quagga.d.ts file in the app folder and the following import statements in the component:

```
import Quagga from './quagga.d';
```

The guide says from 'quagga' but it doesn't work but above works

```
declare const Quagga = require('quagga').default;
```

I have the following code in the constructor of the component like this:

```
constructor() { 

    Quagga.init({
    inputStream : {
      name : "Live",
      type : "LiveStream",
      target: document.querySelector('#yourElement')    // Or '#yourElement' (optional)
    },
    decoder : {
      readers : ["code_128_reader"]
    }
  }, function(err) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return
      }
      console.log("Initialization finished. Ready to start");
      Quagga.start();
  });


 }
```

However, I get the following error:

`Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined` from core.umd.js

and

```
 Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
```

from zone.js

What does this error mean? I can't figure this out! Is there a bug with zone.js?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `angular-cli` or `webpack` or `systemjs` ?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this - I have a systemjs.config.js file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add Quagga to `node_modules` run

```
npm install quagga --save
```

add `js` and `css` dependencies in `index.html` as usual
for example

```
<script src="node_modules/....../qugga.min.js"></script>
```

in `app.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var Quagga:any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
      Quagga.init({
        inputStream : {
          name : "Live",
          type : "LiveStream",
          target: document.querySelector('#yourElement')    // Or '#yourElement' (optional)
        },
        decoder : {
          readers : ["code_128_reader"]
        }
      }, function(err) {
          if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              return
          }
          console.log("Initialization finished. Ready to start");
          Quagga.start();
      });
  }

}
```

Use `ngOnInit` instead of the constructor. While the constructor only instantiates the component, `ngOnInit` will be called after the component is loaded.

Also, take a look at
https://github.com/serratus/quaggaJS/issues/146 for some other help you would need in next step.